# GuzzleHttp no esta loguenado

Tags: laravel, login, guzzle

En un proyecto hecho con Laravel esta incorporada la libreria de GuzzleHttp para hacer una petición a otra página:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => env('API')]);

$tmp = $client->request('GET', 'test', ['auth' => [env('USER'), env('PASS')]]);
```

La ruta el API a la que intenta acceder esta así:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'simpleauth'], function () {
    Route::controllers([
        'api'           =>  'Api',
    ]);
});
```

Pero marca que las credenciales son inválidas, ya revisé las credenciales y están bien, me deja loguearme con los mismos datos a partir del formulario de login, además solo esta pasando en el servidor, en mi localhost funciona perfectamente.

¿Alguien sabe cual puede ser el problema?

Comment: Podrías darnos más información? Desde el navegador puedes acceder a la ruta "api" con credenciales? Es un auth basic?

Comment: Desde el navegador puedo acceder a la ruta del API, pero la introducir las credenciales me marca con son inválidas pero ya verifique y las credenciales son correctas, esto me pasa únicamente en el servidor

Comment: Utilizas apache? FastCGI? Puede ser ese el problema

Answer (score 0):

Según la documentación de [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#http-basic-authentication), si estás utilizando Apache y FastCGI, necesitas añadir dos líneas a tu archivo .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Es la única diferencia que puedes tener con los diferentes entornos.

Answer (score -1):

Asegúrate que el .env del servidor tenga las credenciales correctas, muchas veces tendemos a omitir el .env en el server, ahora bien también puedes hacer un dd(env('USER'),env('PASS')]) para verificar que estas realmente enviando la información correcta